# fwrite() modifying a file in place without fflush() lead to error

Tags: c, fwrite, fflush

write_test() reads file contents and write it back just in place, why would it fail without calling fflush()?

Without calling fflush(), file contents would be in a mess if the file size is several times larger than BUFFSIZE, and the while loop never ends.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void write_test(char* fname);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    write_test(argv[1]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#define BUFFSIZE 1024
void write_test(char* fname)
{
    FILE* filein = fopen(fname, "rb+");
    
    void *buffer=NULL;
    buffer = malloc(BUFFSIZE);
    if (buffer==NULL)return;
    
    fseeko64(filein, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(1)
    {
        int size=fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, filein);
        
        fseeko64(filein, -size, SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, size, filein);
        if(size<BUFFSIZE) break;
        
        //fflush(filein);
    }
    free(buffer);
    fclose(filein);
}
```

Enviromnent:windows10 x64,  gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

I tried to simplify the original code.

Comment: Because the standard [says so](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7).

Comment: The underlying reason is that stdio usually has separate buffers for input and output. `fflush()` ensures that the buffers are sychronized with the file contents. If you don't do this, the next read will read from the input buffer that contains the old file contents.

Comment: You did a seek between read and write, but not between write and read. So apart from not repositioning the file pointer, you aren't testing that you read anything or was at EOF. *"When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function."*

Comment: Thanks, I tried to optimize thr original code by commiting fflush() out, results in lots of broken source file.